# What controller is this?

Tags: control

I'm wondering what type of controller this is? PI right?

[image]

Looks like a PI to me. I from the s in the denominator. P from the K term.

Usually, we've been dealing with PI controller in which the I term just places a pole at origin. I'm just starting control systems and I know this may be a trivial question to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

To earn the 'I' it has to have a bare \$s\$ in the denominator, i.e. \$\frac{k_i}{s}\$.  It's either a lag-lead or a lead-lag, depending on whether \$z\$ is bigger than \$p\$ (lag-lead) or the other way around.  If \$p\$ is very small compared to the process dynamics (i.e., if \$p\$ is 0.01 times or less the loop closing frequency) then some folks may call it a 'leaky integrator' -- I really don't like that term, though.